# Apply dynamic filter operator in SAP HANA

Tags: hana

We are using HANA 1.0 SPS12. Is it possible to handle filter condition dynamically in HANA graphical calculation view.

[image]

IS it possible to program this 'AND'/'OR' by parameter.

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a `WHERE` condition instead. Other than that you would need to model an additional parameter that evaluates to true or false and that you use to have either option active or not. That makes the solution a lot more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to handle the and/or using the following, my example was about searching for year and quarter or for a year and all quarters:

`(match("YEAR",'$$year$$') or in("YEAR",'$$year$$')) and (match("QUARTER",'$$quarter$$') or in ("QUARTER",'$$quarter$$'))`

Perhaps this could work for you:

`(match("CITY",'$$IP_CITY_FILTER$$') or in("CITY",'$$IP_CITY_FILTER$$')) and (match("AMT",'5000') or in ("AMT",'5000'))`